# jQuery How to Disable all Links of a Page Except One

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I will keep it clear and short.
I am looking for a way to disable all links on a page except the one or more I want to be clickable.

Basically I need to disable all link on the page and re-enable only those I want to be enabled. I know jQuery has a way of disabling links, but I am not a pro JS guy.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by binding an event on all anchors. Give the anchors that are allowed to click a class `.allowedLink`.

The function checks if the link has the class. If not, default behaviour is disabled.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function(e) {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('allowedLink')) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Disabled</a><br />
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Disabled</a><br />
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" class="allowedLink">Enabled</a><br />
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Disabled</a>
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it clickable if it contains Clickable inide <a>. Ex: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">Clickable</a>

Comment: @Pabi, sure, change the if to `if( $(this).html() != 'Clickable' )`

Answer (score 1):

Add class for all the links must be clickable and in Jquery you can use

```
$("body").on("click","a:not(.clickable)",function(){return false;});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xnm8rz9g/